# Reload Browser Based on innerHTML Contents

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, innerhtml

I am using AJAX to load content from a PHP file into a div every 5 seconds. This works fine, but I would like to refresh the browser if the contents of the div are equal to "Your item has expired."

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<div id="tableHolder"></div>
```

**Here is my JS:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  refreshTable();
});

function refreshTable(){
    $('#tableHolder').load('ajax_time.php', function(){
       setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
    });
}
```

I think I can use something like:

```
if (document.getElementById('tableHolder').innerHTML == "Your item has expired.")
```

But I'm not sure how to go about putting it together. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    refreshTable();
});


function refreshTable(){
       if($("#tableHolder").text() == "Your item has expired."){
         location.reload();
       } 
   $('#tableHolder').load('ajax_time.php', function(){
      setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! will that refresh the browser?

Comment: this will call your refreshTable function when tableholder contains that particular string.. and then do an ajax call..

Comment: in your function why you have this `setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);`

Comment: I think @Brandon wants the whole page to refresh when "Your item has expired" is shown. In that case ```location.reload(true)``` (instead of the call to refreshTable) should do the trick.

Comment: You both are awesome! Thanks!